# How to conditionally format cells in one sheet based on values in another sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets in a google sheet named `draft` and `players`. Once a player is listed anywhere within `B2:M21` I'd like to add conditional formatting with a strikethrough in the `players` sheet.

`players` sheet

[image]

`draft` sheet

[image]

`draft` sheet after adding a player

[image]

and the according formatting in `players`

[image]

I tried using `=search()` but couldn't quite figure out how to search for the player in each given row instead of one overall search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by using XMATCH to find the name in the full range of the other sheet. For that you'll need to use INDIRECT (since Conditional Formatting doesn't allow by default to access other sheets) and TOCOL to make it a unique column:

```
=XMATCH ($A2,TOCOL(INDIRECT("Draft!A:Z"),1))
```

Adapt the range of the Draft sheet if needed

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Draft!B2:M21"),$A2)
```